# Has anyone invented a cure for Yahrtzeit?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A few days ago, while in shul, I asked my friend if he wanted to meet me for bowling at 5 P.M. He said, "I can't because I have yahrtzeit."

It sounded like a serious sickness, like "I have a cold", but worse. I asked a rabbi about yahrtzeit, and he told me that everyone that has yahrtzeit had some family member that died.

Not only that, but the rabbi explained that people even know in advance when they will get yahrtzeit, because they say things like "I will have yahrtzeit next week."

This sounds like a very serious sickness; almost like a pandemic disease! And, no one is doing anything to stop this sickness. Is there no cure or some cure being developed?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Unfortunately @DanF there is no cure for yahrzeit. Scientific studies have shown strong corellation between yahrzeit and death. Cause-and-effect is however very hard to prove. I have heard recently that scientists are predicting that life span might increase drastically in the near future. However, such would likely only delay the onset of, but not eliminate the fatal yahrzeit.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Yahrzeit is too difficult to cure, for the symptoms of Yahrtzeit don't show untill at least a year after exposure, and with a Shana Meuberet  it only compounds the issues, by the time the symptoms of Yahrzeit begin to show ...its too late. Studies have shown that 99.9% (Eliyahu Hanavi) of people experience Yahrtzeit to either a family member or themselves at some point. Unfortunately,   Modern day treatments have only come so far. Some suggest a more traditional and holistic approach of Kibud Av V'em and Shiluach Hakan as treatments, however this has only slowed the onset and has just resulted in arichus yamim . Other zechuyos are still in their clinical stages of metoch shelo lishma.

Comment: I highly doubt the 99.9% figure. Only one in a thousand are outlived by both parents?

Comment: @Ypnypn Maybe add ... to the nines. Even if both parents are alive there would be a Yahrtzeit of some other relative such as a grandparent.

Answer (score 1):

The cure will be the coming of the mashiach and techiyas hameisim.

This is because the coming of the Mashiach is the time of Techiyas Hameisim and the person whose yahrtzeit is being observed will have returned. So no more Yahrtzeit.